# Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service Abp.Resources.EmbeddedResourceManager was found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I just downloaded the ASP.NET Boilerplate Template for ASP.NET MVC5 with EntityFramework and Module Zero. Running with VS2017, first build / run I encounter an unhandled exception in the project. I have not modified the project in any way other than following the setup instructions, creating the DB using Package Manager Update-Database command etc.

> Startup.cs Line 17 app.UseAbp(); the error is
>   "Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for
>   supporting the service Abp.Resources.EmbeddedResourceManager was
>   found"

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAbp();

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(AccountController.OAuthBearerOptions);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Stack trace is below.

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException occurred
>   HResult=0x80131500 Message=No component for supporting the service
>   Abp.Resources.Embedded.IEmbeddedResourceManager was found
>   Source=Castle.Windsor StackTrace: at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type
>   service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary
>   arguments) at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.ResolveT at
>   Abp.Dependency.IocManager.ResolveT at
>   Abp.Owin.AbpOwinExtensions.UseAbp(IAppBuilder app, Action1
>   optionsAction) at Abp.Owin.AbpOwinExtensions.UseAbp(IAppBuilder app)
>   at MySaaSApp.Web.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in
>   V:\Development\ASP
>   Boilerplate\3.1.3\src\MySaaSApp.Web\App_Start\Startup.cs:line 17

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you restore nuget packages?

Comment: After downloading a fresh copy of the template and building with NuGet package restore at first build the problem no longer occurred.

Comment: you can post your own answer and set as accepted answer

Comment: @Jaycee26 If your answer is worth sharing, post it as an answer.

Comment: I would love to, but I do not know how!  The help seems to indicate I need 15 points to be able to answer my own question!  Any helping doing so glad received,  I'd love to help the community as much as I can.